# App crashes because Android can't find a Java method, despite no problem at compile or install

Tags: android, webview

My Android app runs fine, but:
If I insert a call to WebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled, it crashes saying:

```
Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled, referenced from [my class]
VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 289: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.setScrollbarFadingEnabled (Z)V
```

I am using Android 1.5, not a custom ROM.
My app defines minSdkVersion="3"
I always clean before compiling.

Is setScrollbarFadingEnabled unavailable in Android 1.5?
If so, why don't I receive a compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setScrollbarFadingEnabled is available from sdk 5 and onwards (android 2).
For why you don't get compile errors, your project settings (not AndroidManifest.xml, your eclipse project settings) are probably set to compile against some higher SDK, not 1.5. If you set it to 1.5, it should give you the error properly.